# Rewrite Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

Tags: php, magento

I guess I already know the answer but may be there is a good way to rewrite the class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract without to do it directly in the magento framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can rewrite classes in Magento is because you pass the class you'd like to load through a translation layer, translating from `core/template` to `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, for example.

Abstract classes don't pass through this layer as you reference them directly in the code, e.g. `class Mage_Core_Block_Template extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract {..}`.

If you *really* need to redefine the class, then you'll need to put it higher up the load path, like in the `app/code/local` folder.  I'd reassess why you're doing this, though, as you may be taking the wrong approach, or there may be a better way to achieve your desired outcome.

Comment: I need to rewrite the function getCacheKey for all the block. I implement a module to use multiple languages for only 1 site instead to use 1 site by language. So I have to add in the cache key the current language.

Comment: I looked into the code of module we bought they copy the all class and then rewrite it. It's a bit weird, I think the only way will be to modify directly the code and to keep it up to date for all upgrade :(

Comment: I'm not sure what Magento does with cache keys across stores, but if you do need to redefine it, then put it in `app/code/local`, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Do you mean, I must copy the file with the class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract in my module and then customize it? How should I do then for the config.xml?

Comment: To make it load first, you need to put the class content in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php`, and make your code changes.

Comment: Depending on how you deploy, I would suggest maintaining a set of patches to fix problems in core code.  This could be one of the patches and it could be applied during the build generation.